# What do the Stack/Unstack options do in iOS Photos app?

Tags: ios, photos.app

I am running the iOS 11 beta but don't know if this is a new option or if it's there in 10 too. On some of my photos, there is a Stack or Unstack option on the share sheet. If I select it, nothing seems to happen and I can't find any documentation on it. What do they do?

[image: Share sheet with option highlighted]

Comment: I think unstack separates burst mode photos to individual photos.

Comment: @Harcker, that was my first thought too, but these are not burst photos. Also, I just took a set of burst photos and there is no stack/unstack option on them.

Comment: At what occasions do it happen?

Comment: @Harcker, I've no idea. I've found one or two photos with the option but can't see what is unique about them...OK, I think I've found the pattern. If two photos are an original and HDR version, the original has a "stack" option and the HDR has an "unstack" option. As I said, nothing happens when I select these options but I suspect the idea is if I choose Stack then only one of the two photos (presumably the HDR one) will be visible in the Camera Roll.